# Mapping an entire network drive, not a folder

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares

I click on the 'Map network drive' button on my server's 'Computer'.  There is a line asking for the 'folder' or essentially the network drive location.  I have another server running on the IP 10.132.2.98.  I can map a network drive to the address '\10.132.2.98\myfolder', but I get an error when I try mapping the drive to '\10.132.2.98'.  Is there a way where I can map my entire hard drive on the second server?

Comment: No, you can not..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\\10.132.2.98\C$`. You need to be a member of the remote computer's local `Administrators` group for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in command line:

```
net use x: \\10.132.2.98\C$
```

To login as another user:

```
net use x: \\10.132.2.98\C$ /user:username password
```

It will mount `c:` drive of `10.132.2.98` as `x:`.
Make sure *Administrative Shares* are enabled on host computer or your user has administrative rights on host computer.